# php include necessary files in every file

Tags: php, class, autoload

I have some classes, and a functions.php file, which needs to be loaded on every PHP page I script. (Because some pages could individually get called by $.ajax)

I googled, but couldn't get further than the __autoload function.

Let's say I have 100 pages, with 10 function files and 10 class files in 3 other directories. It would be kind of hard to load them into every page and get the relative paths good from every page, it's impossible.

So the perfect situation would be to call every class/function file ONCE, on index.php and never have to call them again. Is this possible?

How would you call all your classes and function files to use in your website?

Thank you!

Comment: Either use an autoloader, or just make a "meta" include... included files can themselves include other files, so just have a `inc.php` which includes all the other files.  You still end up including your 10+10 files, but only have one single include() in your actual code.

Comment: Why doesn't an autoloader work for you?

Comment: Psst, modern PHP autoloading takes place using [`spl_autoload_register`](http://php.net/spl_autoload_register) and friends.  You can use it to create multiple autoloader handlers, while there can be only one plain vanilla `__autoload`

Comment: @Brad I tried to Google, but I can't find FULL examples of the autoload function. I can't figure out where to put it? And if I find out. Will the autoload function still work when I call a PHP file trough ajax?

Comment: @AngeloA, The documentation is quite clear, and has examples.  If you don't understand it, then ask specifically what the question is.  Basically, you write a function that PHP calls if it can't find a class, and that function figures out what file to include to make that class available.  And yes, PHP doesn't know or care that a request is made via AJAX.  It's still regular ol' HTTP.

Comment: @Brad Maybe it's me, but I just don't understand. But to be more specific. I don't know where I need to place the autoload function.

Comment: The autoloader should be in the code you run on every page, usually in an "init" or "bootstrap" file.  Conveniently, this is also where you should place all of your normal includes.

Comment: Best way would still be bootstrapping, I think. Thank you all for the information.

Comment: @AngeloA, There are other benefits to the autoloader besides the convenience.  It also means that you will only be including stuff that you need.  If a particular code path doesn't need something, it won't be included.  On heavy sites, this is a large benefit.  For smaller sites, it might not matter as much.

Comment: Good information! Thanks Brad

Comment: Hurts my eyes a negative vote count on this question

Answer (score -4):

include_once('File path here')

Comment: This is not what the OP wants at all. He needs to avoid including each PHP file everywhere in its application

Comment: @koopajah, Well it's part of it.

Comment: No it's not. He does not have problems with file included multiple times. He just has multiple classes and functions files that are needed throughout its application/website and does not want to have to include each file every time he needs it somewhere.

Comment: @koopajah Exactly, thank you. It would be perfect if I have to include it just one time and never have to write it again.